# Redirection from sub directory to its parent directory via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two websites. One is in root directory and the other one is in sub-directory.
I would like to make sure that when someone visits sub-directory website he should see content of the main website. How I can load content from a parent directory with the same URL?

If it is not possible than I will like to implement redirection from this sub directory to its parent directory.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this with a combination of [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.getcwd.php) and [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php). If `getcwd` returns a string which contains the keyword we are talking about, then using `chdir` you can make sure that the main directory is being used. However, you will need to make sure that this is the first thing to run before any `include`s or `require`s for each requests. Depending on the quality of the planning of your project this could range from trivial to extremely difficult. Also, check all usages of `chdir` in the subfolder to see whether they would defeat the purpose of your fix.